# Head twitches (?) when screaming

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example sentence: "She screamed in a shrill voice, her head ***(...)*** from the force of which she had screamed."

I've searched the words shake, twitch, convulse, jerk. However, if any of these are what would fit in this kind of sentence, how would I use it in another in the same context? Any part-of-speech is fine. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated. I will use it to write a horror story.

Comment: *Shaking* is fine. What's not fine is the entire rest of the sentence that follows, rendering futile all your efforts to pick the best word.